# In TypeScript, why is the function return type not assigned to generic type as expected?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this code in TypeScript and the `ParsedData` generic type is not populated correctly. I don't understand what's preventing TS from inferring the correct type below.

```
function fromData<RawData, ParsedData>(rawData: RawData) {
    return function withParser(
        parser: (data: RawData) => ParsedData,
        renderer: (parsedData: ParsedData) => unknown
    ) {
        const parsedData = parser(rawData)
        
        return {
            renderedData: renderer(parsedData),
            parsedData
        }
    }
}

const hasData = fromData({ user: 1 })

hasData(
    (rawData) => rawData.user + 1,
    (parsedData) => parsedData + 100 // PROBLEM: 'parsedData' is of type 'unknown'.(18046) 
)
```

In general, I would like to call a function with some data and receive another function that can be called at a later time with a `parser` and `renderer` arguments that infer correct types throughout.

I'm expecting to see `parsedData` to be correctly typed in my IDE, so that I can more easily implement a `renderer` function using the return type of the `parser` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `ParsedData` is a type parameter of `fromData`, and at the `fromData` call the `ParsedData` type has not been determined yet. You can fix it by instead parameterizing the returned function with `ParsedData`:

```
function fromData<RawData>(rawData: RawData) {
    return function withParser<ParsedData>(
        parser: (data: RawData) => ParsedData,
        renderer: (parsedData: ParsedData) => unknown
    ) {
        const parsedData = parser(rawData)

        return {
            renderedData: renderer(parsedData),
            parsedData
        }
    }
}
```

```
const hasData = fromData({ user: 1 })

hasData(
    (rawData) => rawData.user + 1,
    (parsedData) => parsedData + 100
    // (parameter) parsedData: number
)
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOxryN)